# VBA Access: How to zip and encrypt a directory from VBA Access?

Tags: ms-access, encryption, vba

Do how does one go about Zipping a directory and and encrypting the zip file using VBA Access using the windows standard zip function?

So far i have managed to find code which Creates a Zip file and moves the files from the directory to the zip file. However the Zip file is not encrypted. See Code below:

```
Public Function AddFilesToZip()

Dim objFSO As Object, objZip As Object, objShell As Object
Dim objFolder As Object, objFile As Object
Dim sngStart As Single
Dim strPath As String, strZip As String
Dim inputfile As DAO.Recordset
Set inputfile = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT InputFilepath, Format(End_of_Month, 'yyyymmdd')  FROM CONFIG WHERE Active = True;")
strPath = inputfile(0)  'Path to read files from


strZip = strPath & "Test Import Files " & inputfile(1) & ".zip"  'Output zip file

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objZip = objFSO.CreateTextFile(strZip)
objZip.WriteLine Chr(80) & Chr(75) & Chr(5) & Chr(6) & String(18, 0)
objZip.Close

Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strPath)

    'loop through files - adding them to the zip
For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
    If objFile <> strZip Then
    'objShell.NameSpace("" & strZip).CopyHere objFile.Path
    objShell.NameSpace("" & strZip).MoveHere objFile.Path
    sngStart = Timer
    Do While Timer < sngStart + 2
        DoEvents
    Loop
    End If
Next



End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably not what you were hoping for but, unfortunately, the Windows shell function for zipping (or *compressed folders*) does not do encryption. It's a very simple way to group files together in a compressed form and nothing more.

After you create the zip file, you would need to use third-party tool or library to encrypt your zip file by calling it through the VBA `Shell` function or similar mechanism. Of course, the downside is that any such tool will need to be installed on the computer before you can use it.

On the plus side, you don't need all that awkward code for the shell zipping part of the task, because such tools can zip and encrypt at the same time; just make sure you read what command-line options you need to pass.

Comment: How would i go about encrypting the file using a library?

Comment: There's the DotNetZip library, for example which, according to its website, can be used from scripting environments like VBA. I haven't tried any of this personally, so I can't tell you with certainty, although the third-party tool option should work without problems, since it's just like executing them in the command line.